# Drupal RSS view with get parameter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, rss

it is possible to have my RSS feed view accessible with get parameter in url (ex. example.com/taxonomy/feed?token=tJHqoIaixc) I have tried to put ?token=tJHqoIaixc after url, but it does not show the RSS Feed. Any ideas?

Should i use some filters for that? The token can be hardcoded, it does have to change every time

Comment: it'd for on TID ? (because it's missing into your url) . it's to access from anonymous user  ?

Comment: I would like to just hide this RSS feed for people who knows the exact url, it doesnt matter what would be after token=